# How to 'listen' production branch from another repo on Heroku?

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, hook, production

recently I'm using Heroku to host and deploy some Node.js applications and it works perfect for me with the 'git push' to upload all and put it into production.

Now, i'm wondering how i can link my Heroku app with another git repo (i.e. github), and 'listen' the production branch to keep in production only the official releases?

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a service designed for this purpose. [Strider](https://striderapp.com/) is one example.

To do this yourself, you could set up a host to respond to post-receive hooks from GitHub and then push to Heroku.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it ;)